# onClick inside ListActivity using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, onclick, listactivity

I've got a class that creates a list from a DB using SimpleCursorAdapter. I want to add an onClick event to each item in the list but I don't know where to place the code.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would override the `onListItemClick` method.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(this.getIntent().getData(), id);
    // your code
}
```

Comment: i've been looking for the answer to this for so long and it was THIS SIMPLE. <3